# How to add and edit the wp_editor field in the taxonomy(manually)?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, tinymce

I need to add the custom field with wp_editor/tiny MCE to the product cat taxonomy.
I already added the simple text and textarea like the taxonomy field like that

```
add_action( 'product_cat_add_form_fields', 'cxc_taxonomy_add_new_meta_field', 10, 2 );

function cxc_taxonomy_add_new_meta_field() {
    // this will add the custom meta field to the add new term page
    ?>
    <div class="form-field">
        <label for="custom_term_meta"><?php _e( 'Custom meta field', 'cxc-codexcoach' ); ?></label>
        <input type="text" name="custom_term_meta" id="custom_term_meta" value="">      
        <p class="description"><?php _e( 'Enter a value for this field','cxc-codexcoach' ); ?></p>
    </div>
    <?php
}

add_action( 'product_cat_edit_form_fields', 'cxc_taxonomy_edit_meta_field', 10, 2 );

function cxc_taxonomy_edit_meta_field( $term ) {

    // put the term ID into a variable
    $term_id = $term->term_id;

    // retrieve the existing value(s) for this meta field. This returns an array
    $term_meta = get_term_meta( $term_id, 'custom_term_meta', true ); ?>
    <tr class="form-field">
        <th scope="row" valign="top"><label for="custom_term_meta"><?php _e( 'Example meta field', 'cxc-codexcoach' ); ?></label></th>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="custom_term_meta" id="custom_term_meta" value="<?php echo ( !empty($term_meta) ) ? $term_meta  : ''; ?>">                  
            <p class="description"><?php _e( 'Enter a value for this field','cxc-codexcoach' ); ?></p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <?php
}

add_action( 'edited_product_cat', 'cxc_save_taxonomy_custom_meta', 10, 2 );  
add_action( 'create_product_cat', 'cxc_save_taxonomy_custom_meta', 10, 2 );

function cxc_save_taxonomy_custom_meta( $term_id ) {
    if ( isset( $_POST['custom_term_meta'] ) && !empty( $_POST['custom_term_meta'] ) ) {
        update_term_meta( $term_id, 'custom_term_meta', $_POST['custom_term_meta'] );
    }
}
```

I've made the same to add TinyMCE field

```
add_action( 'product_cat_add_form_fields', 'cxc_taxonomy_add_new_meta_field', 10, 2 );

function cxc_taxonomy_add_new_meta_field() {
    // this will add the custom meta field to the add new term page
    ?>
    <div class="form-field">
        <label for="custom_term_meta"><?php _e( 'Custom meta field', 'cxc-codexcoach' ); ?></label>
        <?php
        wp_editor(get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'custom_term_meta', true ), 'custom_term_meta', array(
            'wpautop'       => 1,
            'media_buttons' => 1,
            'textarea_name' => 'custom_term_meta',
            'textarea_rows' => 5,
            'tabindex'      => null,
            'editor_css'    => '<style>.quicktags-toolbar, .wp-editor-tools, .wp-editor-wrap, .wp-switch-editor {padding: 5px 10px;}</style>',
            'editor_class'  => 'form-field',
            'teeny'         => 0,
            'dfw'           => 0,
            'tinymce'       => 1,
            'quicktags'     => 1,
            'drag_drop_upload' => false
        ) );?>
        <p class="description"><?php _e( 'Enter a value for this field','cxc-codexcoach' ); ?></p>
    </div>
    <?php
}
```

But if I copy the same code to 'edit' part, it wouldn't work, because there's no 'value'

```
add_action( 'product_cat_edit_form_fields', 'cxc_taxonomy_edit_meta_field', 10, 2 );

function cxc_taxonomy_edit_meta_field( $term ) {

    // put the term ID into a variable
    $term_id = $term->term_id;

    // retrieve the existing value(s) for this meta field. This returns an array
    $term_meta = get_term_meta( $term_id, 'custom_term_meta', true ); ?>
    <tr class="form-field">
        <th scope="row" valign="top"><label for="custom_term_meta"><?php _e( 'Example meta field', 'cxc-codexcoach' ); ?></label></th>
        <td>
            <?php
        wp_editor(get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'custom_term_meta', true ), 'custom_term_meta', array(
            'wpautop'       => 1,
            'media_buttons' => 1,
            'textarea_name' => 'custom_term_meta',
            'textarea_rows' => 5,
            'tabindex'      => null,
            'editor_css'    => '<style>.quicktags-toolbar, .wp-editor-tools, .wp-editor-wrap, .wp-switch-editor {padding: 5px 10px;}</style>',
            'editor_class'  => 'form-field',
            'teeny'         => 0,
            'dfw'           => 0,
            'tinymce'       => 1,
            'quicktags'     => 1,           
            'drag_drop_upload' => false
        ) );?>
            <p class="description"><?php _e( 'Enter a value for this field','cxc-codexcoach' ); ?></p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <?php
}
```

I tried to add

```
'value' => '',
```

and

```
'value' => '( !empty($term_meta) ) ? $term_meta  : " " ',
```

It didn't help, what's the right way? I need to do it manually by the code

Answer (score 0):

```
add_action( 'product_cat_add_form_fields', 'cxc_taxonomy_add_new_meta_field', 10, 2 );

function cxc_taxonomy_add_new_meta_field() {
  // this will add the custom meta field to the add new term page
  ?>
  <div class="form-field">
    <label for="custom_term_meta"><?php _e( 'Custom meta field', 'cxc-codexcoach' ); ?></label>
    <!--<input type="text" name="custom_term_meta" id="custom_term_meta" value="">-->
    <?php 
     $term_id = $term->term_id; 
    wp_editor(get_term_meta( $term_id, 'custom_term_meta', true ), 'custom_term_meta', array(
      'wpautop'       => 1,
      'media_buttons' => 1,
      'textarea_name' => 'custom_term_meta',
      'textarea_rows' => 5,
      'tabindex'      => null,
      'editor_css'    => '<style>.quicktags-toolbar, .wp-editor-tools, .wp-editor-wrap, .wp-switch-editor {padding: 5px 10px;}</style>',
      'editor_class'  => 'form-field tinyeditor',
      'teeny'         => 0,
      'dfw'           => 0,
      'tinymce'       => 1,
      'quicktags'     => 1,             
      'drag_drop_upload' => false
    ) );?>
    <p class="description"><?php _e( 'Enter a value for this field','cxc-codexcoach' ); ?></p>
  </div>
  <?php
}

add_action( 'product_cat_edit_form_fields', 'cxc_taxonomy_edit_meta_field', 10, 2 );

function cxc_taxonomy_edit_meta_field( $term ) {

  // put the term ID into a variable
  $term_id = $term->term_id;

  // retrieve the existing value(s) for this meta field. This returns an array
  $term_meta = get_term_meta( $term_id, 'custom_term_meta', true ); ?>
  <tr class="form-field">
    <th scope="row" valign="top"><label for="custom_term_meta"><?php _e( 'Example meta field', 'cxc-codexcoach' ); ?></label></th>
    <td>
      <!--<input type="text" name="custom_term_meta" id="custom_term_meta" value="<?php echo ( !empty($term_meta) ) ? $term_meta  : ''; ?>">-->
      <?php 
        wp_editor(get_term_meta( $term_id, 'custom_term_meta', true ), 'custom_term_meta', array(
          'wpautop'       => 1,
          'media_buttons' => 1,
          'textarea_name' => 'custom_term_meta',
          'textarea_rows' => 5,
          'tabindex'      => null,
          'editor_css'    => '<style>.quicktags-toolbar, .wp-editor-tools, .wp-editor-wrap, .wp-switch-editor {padding: 5px 10px;}</style>',
          'editor_class'  => 'form-field tinyeditor',
          'teeny'         => 0,
          'dfw'           => 0,
          'tinymce'       => 1,
          'quicktags'     => 1, 
          'value'       => TRUE,
          'drag_drop_upload' => false
        ) );?>
      <p class="description"><?php _e( 'Enter a value for this field','cxc-codexcoach' ); ?></p>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <?php
}

add_action( 'edited_product_cat', 'cxc_save_taxonomy_custom_meta', 10, 2 );  
add_action( 'create_product_cat', 'cxc_save_taxonomy_custom_meta', 10, 2 );

function cxc_save_taxonomy_custom_meta( $term_id ) {
  if ( isset( $_POST['custom_term_meta'] ) && !empty( $_POST['custom_term_meta'] ) ) {
    update_term_meta( $term_id, 'custom_term_meta', $_POST['custom_term_meta'] );
  }
}
```